# Un "disservizio" si "arreca" o semplicemente si "fa"?

Tags: word-choice

È corretto usare il verbo *arrecare* col complemento oggetto *disservizio*?

La domanda viene semplicemente dal dubbio che *fare un disservizio* possa essere uno dei tantissimi usi di *fare* in luogo di verbi più appropriati.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Io non userei proprio l'espressione *fare* o *arrecare un disservizio*, suona strana in italiano corrente.

Nel significato che tu desideri, userei *fare un cattivo servizio* o *rendere un cattivo servizio*, è questo il modo di dire usuale. *Fare* è più colloquiale.

O anche *arrecare un disagio*, dipende dal significato nel contesto.

*Disservizio* attualmente ha assunto il significato di malfunzionamento di un servizio, pubblico o privato.

*Disservizio* come sinonimo di cattivo servizio è considerato desueto o letterario, vedi i seguenti link:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/disservizio/

https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/disservizio.shtml

Anche il dizionario Oxford lo dà come arcaico.  Scusa, ma non mi funziona il link all'Oxford, metto l'immagine:

[image: e]